# Python lxml library, making element with variables as attribute names

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to dynamically create a .xml file from the information found in an excel spreadsheet.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create an xml element where I can use variables for the name of the attribute and the value of the attribute

```
from lxml import etree

attribute = "state"
attribute_value = "NJ"
root = etree.Element()
root.append(etree.Element("Entry1", attribute = attribute_value))
```

However it is just ignoring the fact that attribute is a variable with a value of "state", and it is instead naming the attribute "attribute".

I am inexperienced with both Python and especially lxml. I've looked through the docs and searched here for some answers but couldn't find anything similar. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you post your entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a dynamic argument to function, you should use python argument unpacking: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Use `**` to unpack a dictionary to function arguments:

```
function_name(**arguments_dict)
```

And here is the code you need

```
from lxml import etree

attribute_name = "state"
attribute_value = "NJ"
attributes = {attribute_name: attribute_value}

root = etree.Element('root')
root.append(etree.Element("Entry1", **attributes))

print(etree.tostring(root))
```